# Question about resolution of free function names in C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates

This program works as expected:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void output(T t) {
   prt(t);
}

struct It {
   It(int* p) : p(p) {}
   int* p;
};

void prt(It it) {
   std::cout << *(it.p) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   int val = 12;
   It it(&val);
   output(it);    
   return 0;
}
```

When you compile and execute this, it prints "12" as it should. Even though the function **prt**, required by the **output** template function, is defined after **output**, **prt** is visible at the point of instantiation, and therefore everything works.

The program below is very similar to the program above, but it fails to compile:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void output(T t) {
   prt(t);
}

void prt(int* p) {
   std::cout << (*p) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   int val = 12;
   output(&val);
   return 0;
}
```

This code is trying to do the same thing as the previous example, but this fails in gcc 8.2 with the error message:

```
     'prt' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by
 argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
```

The only thing that changed is that the argument passed to **output** is a built-in type, rather than a user-defined type. But I didn't think that should matter for name resolution. So my question is: 1) why does the second example fail?; and 2) why does one example fail and the other succeeds?

Comment: msvc doesn't mind it, but clang fails, too https://godbolt.org/z/8ehE-8 . I think the part about: 
<source>:8:6: note: 'void prt(int*)' declared here, later in the translation" is quite telling - the compiler sees the definition, it just chooses not to use it.   I'm guessing it has to do with ADL and how ADL finds built-in types vs user-declared types.

Comment: That is an interesting thought, but I don't see how ADL could play a role here: in the examples, everything lives in the same namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Standard rule that applies here is found in [[temp.dep.candidate]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.dep.candidate):

> For a function call where the *postfix-expression* is a dependent name, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules ([basic.lookup.unqual], [basic.lookup.argdep]) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup, only function declarations from the template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces ([basic.lookup.argdep]), only function declarations found in either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.

In both examples, unqualified name lookup finds no declarations of `prt`, since there were no such declarations before the point where the template was defined.  So we move on to argument-dependent lookup, which looks only in the associated namespaces of the argument types.

Class `It` is a member of the global namespace, so the global namespace is the one associated namespace, and the one declaration is visible within that namespace in the template instantiation context.

A pointer type `U*` has the same associated namespaces as type `U`, and a fundamental type has no associated namespaces at all.  So since the only argument type `int*` is a pointer to fundamental type, *there are no associated namespaces*, and argument-dependent lookup can't possibly find any declarations in the second program.

I can't exactly say why the rules were designed this way, but I would guess the intent is that a template should either use the specific declared functions it meant to use, or else use a function as an extensible customization point, but those user customizations need to be closely related to a user-defined type they will work with.  Otherwise, it becomes possible to change the behavior of a template that really meant to use one specific function or function template declaration by providing a better overload for some particular case.  Admittedly, this is more from the viewpoint of when there is at least one declaration in the template definition context, not when that lookup finds nothing at all, but then we get into cases where SFINAE was counting on not finding something, etc.

Comment: Yup, I think this is it, thanks. I found more details in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl.